# Mapping routes on a domain to different backend heroku apps

Tags: unix, heroku, routes, saas, paas

Let's say I have two web apps on Heroku. For example `foobar-signup.heroku.com`, and `foobar-conferences.heroku.com`.

If I wanted to map routes from under `www.foobar.com/signup` and `www.foobar.com/conferences` to the same routes on those two backend apps (i.e. `www.foobar-signup.heroku.com/signup`, ...), what services, applications, and configurations should I use to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proxy pass to do that.

For that, you can use apache (as it is very easy to use). Now in your proxy file, you have to map all requests from 
**www.foobar.com/signup** to **www.foobar-signup.heroku.com/signup** 
and
**www.foobar.com/conferences** to **www.foobar-conferences.heroku.com/conferences**

Now when you open **www.foobar.com/signup** page, proxy pass will redirect it to **www.foobar-signup.heroku.com/signup** page. Thereby solving your problem.

Edit your httd.conf file,

```
    ProxyPass /signup/  http://www.foobar-signup.heroku.com/signup/
    ProxyPass /conferences/  http://www.foobar-conferences.heroku.com/conferences/
```